# How to create a rule to stop desktop alerts for certain emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to create a rule so that certain emails do not generate a desktop alert (the pop-ups that appear bottom-right of the screen).

I know I can globally enable or disable desktop alerts, but is it possible to control it for particular emails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could control it via disabling the global desktop alerts, and then having a rule at the bottom of the rules list that displays an alert for every message. The trick is to have a rule higher in the list (ie, runs prior to the desktop alert rule) that handles these certain emails that includes the option to "stop processing more rules" on step 1 of the rule creation wizard.

**To disable global desktop alerts**, navigate as follows:

File -> Options -> Mail -> Message arrival

Then deselect the 'Display a Desktop Alert' option.

**To display alerts for all other emails**, Go to your inbox, then select

Rules -> Manage Rules and Alerts -> New Rule

From here, click:

'Apply rule on messages I receive' -> Next -> Next -> 'display a Desktop Alert' -> Finish

Then use the arrows to move the rule to the bottom.